# Differentiation of pseudo-function

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I am having problems solving the following question.

Let $F(x)=h(g(f(x))),$ where $f(2)=4, g(4)=4, f\prime(2)=3 , g\prime(4)=6 , $and $h\prime(4)=10$

Then $F\prime(2)$ equals. . .

I am assuming I am to use the `Chain rule` but am uncertain on how to use the `Chain rule` without given a function with variables.

Given $f(x) = (3x^2 + 4x)^2 \\ 
f`(x)g(x)g`(x) \\
2(3x^2 + 4x)(6x+4)$

What I currently think the solution is, is:

$F\prime(2) = h\prime(g(x)*g\prime(x))\\ = h\prime(g\prime(f(x)*f\prime(x))g\prime(x))\\=4320$

But this is clearly not the correct solution. Please inform me where I have made a mistake.

Thank you,

Comment: $F'(x)=h'(g(f(x)))\times g'(f(x))\times f'(x)$ as far chain rule is concerned .

Comment: Assuming your definition of $F(x)=h(g(f(x)))$ is correct, do you have specific information concerning function $h$? Something about $h'(4)$, perhaps?

Comment: @SujithZis so according to $F′(x)=h′(g(f(x)))×g′(f(x))×f′(x)$ the answer would be $10*4*4*6*4*3$?

Comment: @Miroslav no i think the answer must be $10*6*3$ according to the formula which i gave , we are only multiplying three terms here , see the brackets carefully ,